# How to best continuously move data from one external stream to another

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a `NamedPipeClientStream` and I want to wire it to a `TCPClient` stream bidirectionally in the most efficient way possible (so that as data comes into one stream it gets written out to the other stream and vice versa).

Is there an existing simple async method to join these together? My google-fu has failed me.

I was planning to just chain some async tasks together using continue with:

```
ReadlineInA() -> WriteLineOutB() -> ReadLineInA() -> ...
```

...and:

```
ReadLineInB() -> WriteLineOutA() -> ReadlineInB() -> ...
```

...unless there is a "cleaner" way. I investigated `System.IO.Pipelines` but that seems to more address internal process communication rather than tying two external streams together.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question, this is what the CopyToAsync method is for. I'm actually using .NET objects in powershell so this is how it is done in powershell

```
$namedToTCPTask = $tcpStream.CopyToAsync($pipeClient)
$TCPTonamedTask = $pipeClient.CopyToAsync($tcpStream)
```